# It wouldn't print the results through awk. How do I fix this?

Tags: sh

I wanted to make a program that searches all the lines that contains all the factors given, from a file 'mydata'. I tried to egrep first factor from mydata and save it in a variable 'a'. Then, I tried to egrep the next factor from a and save the result to a again until I egrep all the factors. When that is done I should have the result in a, so I put a in awk command to print it in the format that I want(display.awk).

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
        echo -e  "Usage: phoneA searchfor [...searchfor]\n(You didn't tell me what you want to search for.)"

else
        a=""

        for i in $*
        do
        if [ -z "$a" ]
        then
                a=$(egrep "$i" mydata)
        else
                a=$(printf '$s' "$a" | egrep "$i")
        fi
        done

        awk -f display.awk "$a"
fi

// until here is the main code

BEGIN{FS="|"}
{print "--------------->";}
{print "name : "$1;}
{print "address : "$2;}
{print "phone : "$3;}
{print "<---------------";}

// this is display.awk
/*
The data in 'mydata' is in the format of
Name | Address | PhoneNumber
*/
```

If I give factors, Name and Address, it should print
--------------->, 
name : Name, 
address : Address, 
phone : PhoneNumber, 
<--------------- one each line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple errors in the program that cause your problem.

1. printf formatting parameters begin with `%`, not `$`:

```
    a=$(printf '$s' "$a" | egrep "$i")
```

should be:

```
    a=$(printf '%s' "$a" | egrep "$i")
```

2. `$a` is a variable not a file, so feed it to awk using printf, the same as you did for egrep:

```
    awk -f display.awk "$a"
```

can become:

```
    printf '%s' "$a" | awk -f display.awk
```

---

There is a potential issue with the output: you will get leading and trailing spaces because the field separator is really **SPACE VERTICAL-BAR SPACE** rather than  just **VERTICAL-BAR**.

Comment: Thank you so much!
It was my first time coding with shell, so I made a lot of mistakes.
But thanks to you, I was able to finish my homework!